# hive error with partition by

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

Here is my create table

```
CREATE TABLE parquetpoc.employee USING PARQUET
LOCATION '/mnt/adlsQA/parquetPOC/output/employee'
PARTITIONED BY (`snapshot_year_month` string,`snapshot_day` string)
```

In the `PARTITIONED BY` I have tried, quotes, single quotes, double quotes, no quotes, and this thing `.

My folder structure is

```
/mnt/adlsQA/parquetPOC/output/employee/snapshot_year_month=201807/snapshot_day=01
```

I am getting this error

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
extraneous input 'string' expecting ')'(line 3, pos 60)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: change to **`snapshot_year_month` string,`snapshot_day` string** .. you have closing backtick after datatype for the first column.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I tried that, same error. (Updated original post with the code I tried)

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you are trying to do? do you have some data on HDFS and you are trying to add them to the table? when does the error appear: while creating table or when querying data? Your table definition looks strange as you don't have any columns apart from partitions